# Is it possible to extend a dynamic spatial (space-time) panel model to a SARAR (SAC) specification?

Tags: panel-data, markov-chain-montecarlo, spatial

I have panel data of 200 regions over 20 years. My goal is to estimate a dynamic spatial (space-time) panel model. I would like to employ an extension of the model used in Debarsy/Ertur/LeSage (2009): "Interpreting dynamic space-time panel data models" and in Parent/LeSage: "Spatial dynamic panel data models with random effects," *Regional Science & Urban Economics*. 2012, Volume 42, Issue 4, pp. 727-738.

The basic dynamic spatial model is:

$$Y_t= ϕY_{t-1} + ρWY_t + θWY_{t-1}+X_tβ+ WX_tγ + ε_t$$

1. Is it possible to add lagged exogenous covariates?

   Referring to Anselin (2008) in "The Econometric of Panel Data" (page: 647), this would result in an identification  problem, since $Y_{t-1}$ already includes $X_{t-1}$.
2. I want to use a "two-way" (region and year) fixed effects specification instead of random effects. Does that lead to any complications?

   In my view, it should be possible to de-mean the data first and then apply the MCMC sampler in the usual fashion. Is that correct?
3. As a last step, I try to add a non-dynamic spatial error term (SAR). Note that the spatial weights (row-standardized) are different for the spatial lag (Durbin part) and spatial error. Is that possible?

   The full model would be:

   $$Y_t= ϕY_{t-1}+ ρWY_t + θWY_{t-1} + X_tβ + WX_t γ + μ_i + θ_t + ε_t$$

   $$ε_t= λMε_t + u_t$$